# Change Bootstrap Vue pagination programmatically

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, pagination, vuex, bootstrap-vue

is there any way to change **b-pagination** in **bootstrap-vue** programmatically like this:

```js
this.$refs.pagination.goToPage(3) // This is just example
```

or using the pagination plugin like this:

```js
this.$bvPagination.goToPage('pagination', 3) // This is just example too
```

I'm trying to find the documentation of the **bootstrap-vue pagination plugin** but I didn't found it yet. I was thought that has something like **$bvPagination** as there is **$bvModal** in **modal plugin**.

Using **v-model** didn't work for me, the page was still in page 1.

```html
<b-pagination
   v-model="pagination.currentPage"
   :total-rows="pagination.totalItems"
   first-number
   last-number
   :per-page="pagination.selectedAmount"
/>
```

in mounted method :

```js
mounted() {
  this.pagination.currentPage = this.$store.state.app.lastPage
}
```

in watch :

```js
watch: {
  'pagination.currentPage': function (page) {
    this.$store.commit('app/UPDATE_LAST_PAGE', page)
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `@input` in your **b-pagination**

```js
<b-pagination
   v-model="pagination.currentPage"
   :total-rows="pagination.totalItems"
   first-number
   last-number
   :per-page="pagination.selectedAmount"
   @input="redirectPage"
/>
```

```js
redirectPage(){
   this.$router.push({path: `/page/${this.currentPage}` });
 }
```

The `input` event triggers every time after a value is modified.

So now if you just change the value of `currentPage` programmatically it should work.

```js
this.currentPage = 3 //this should redirect you since the 
                     //currentPage is changed and redirectPage will be triggered.
```

This approach basically works with UI as well as programmatically, meaning if user clicks pagination the redirect will trigger else if you change this.currentPage it will work.